# number of keys in a JavaMapWithStateDStream in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

here I found a nice proof that mapWithState can handle 10x so many keys as the updateStateByKey function: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/01/faster-stateful-stream-processing-in-apache-spark-streaming.html
my question is: Is there any hard limit for the number of keys in a JavaMapWithStateDStream? are there any performance results known? doese it scale well? I would like to know if it will be possible to manage over 100m keys in the mapWithState efficiently and what environment I would need for this.

Comment: This question is way to broad. I can tell you I'm currently using `mapWithState` in production with hundreds of thousands of concurrent key value pairs (haven't reached millions yet) and it's scaling nicely.

Comment: well I am interested in all sort of reference projects and tests results with really big data that is why the question is so broad and open. I can't find any reference tests online. Currently I am testing with 10m keys and it is running ok. but 100m do not. I would like to know if anybody did that efficiently or tested this behaviour and I can still optimize or if it won't possible for such a use case.

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131074/number-of-keys-in-a-javamapwithstatedstream-in-spark-streaming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we didn't find any performance benchmarks on this on the Internet, we performed a few stress tests of our own. 
Our algorithm require a growing set of keys and there is no upper limit for the number of keys. Unfortunetaly I can't publish the code.
While working on 10m keys everything was ok, but it got very slow while the set of keys got several times as big. And the checkpointing took very long. 
We tested our solution on one, two and four machines in a cluster and although the performance got a bit better we never achieved the 100m keys limit.
So as it seems not to be reliable enaugh for our use case, where we have many complicated states to be managed, we outsourced managing of the state for our keys to an external database instead of using mapWithStates in our application. 
The stress testing is much better. At least the 100m keys limit is not a problem at all.
We still would appreciate any news concerning this topic.